# How to sort filenames correctly like Finder in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, sorting, binding, nsmutablearray, nstableview

I am binding NStableView with NSMutableArray contiaining filenames and other file details.
Simple biniding and sorting with compare: is not properly sorting file names like finder.
Please let me know if i need to define custom selector for sorting filenames and how?

Comment: Define properly sorting.

Comment: thanks for helping me. It seems that i have made the filename sorting working using custom selector like following:

// category on NSString for custom comparison
@interface NSString (FilesComparison)
- (NSComparisonResult)compareFiles:(NSString*)file;
@end
@implementation NSString (FilesComparison) 
- (NSComparisonResult)compareFiles:(NSString*)file {
 return [(NSString *)self compare:file options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSNumericSearch];
}
@end

Thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from Mac OS X 10.6 just use `-[NSString localizedStandardCompare:]`.

For earlier systems see [Technical Q&A QA1159: Sorting Like the Finder](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1159/_index.html)

Comment: I just spent few hours trying to find how to sort files as Finder and I think this info will be useful as it is not easy to find it :)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @rmaddy fixed the link

Answer (score 2):

using custom selector in TableColumn Attribute special thanks to KennyTM

```
// category on NSString for custom comparison
@interface NSString (FilesComparison)
- (NSComparisonResult)compareFiles:(NSString*)file;
@end
@implementation NSString (FilesComparison) 
- (NSComparisonResult)compareFiles:(NSString*)file {
    return [(NSString *)self compare:file options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSNumericSearch];
}
@end
```